# Oracle Apex 20 - Interactive Report not showing any rows on refresh

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an interactive report in Oracle Apex 20.  I have it set to reload using a dynamic action when a modal dialogue is closed. (When an item is added or deleted).

However, when the region containing the interactive report is reloaded, all the rows in the interactive report disappear.

I used the debug tool, and the debug message says:

```
Access to undefined Per Request (Memory Only) variable P201_OCCURRENCE_ID

0 rows fetched.
```

Is there a setting that I need to change in order for this refresh to work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried changing **Maintain Session State** of your page item **P201_OCCURRENCE_ID**? If you have **Per Request (Memory Only)**, the value of the page item will only store that value for the life of a single request. If you are going to need to reference that value later (such as your interactive report being reloaded), you will want to change it to **Per Session (Disk)**.

[image: Apex page designer]

Comment: Yes that fixed it!! Thank you.

Comment: After searching for a couple of hours I found my answer. Thank you, Thank you!