Apex report region disappears after refresh
in my Oracle APEX application i have a report and a form (that updates/creates for that table), i created a dynamic action that refreshes the report after the dialog box is closed (something not new to me and i do it quite frequently).
dynamic action -> Event : dialog closed
action -> refresh, select type: region

my issue is that sometimes, for reasons i do not know, the report disappears completely and i have to refresh the page another time (manually) to display it, this usually happens when the page has many reports, each opening a different dialog box.
why is that? and how to solve it?

Are you using any page items in the query used by your report? Are the session state on those page items set correctly? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65327945/oracle-apex-20-interactive-report-not-showing-any-rows-on-refresh?rq=2

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

sorry for the late reply, that person has almost the same problem i have except he refreshes and item whereas i refresh a region, i do not have that option of maintaining session state for a region.
